# What font has no descent? or How remove the descender of individual characters?

Tags: fonts

I need a font for a project that has no descenders below the baseline.
Here is a link that explains font [terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface):

The descent is the part of a letter that dips below the baseline. For example, the only the lower case of letters g,j,p,q and y seem to have descenders. I would like the bottom of the descent to rest on the baseline for these characters.

If this is not possible, is it possible to force individual characters to stand above the baseline? I am not working in html for this work, but using Adobe Illustrator (or acrobat). I see how to ungroup letters in illustrator, but I have such a large volume that this option is a last straw only.

This [webpage](http://www.myfonts.com/search/ocr-b/) is the best source I've font to preview fonts. I've tested the ocr-x and helvetica lineups so far. They seem to be the best fit for what I need.

Comment: Look for [unicase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicase) fonts. An example is [Alphabet 26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradbury_Thompson#Alphabet_26).

Comment: Create two separate questions, don't ask them all here. Check [help] for more information.

Comment: Are there any descenders _above_ the baseline? : )

Comment: The correct term is descender. That part of a letter that lies below the baseline is called the descender. The word descent has no typographical connection.

Answer (score 2):

Most [small caps](http://ilovetypography.com/2008/02/20/small-caps/) variants have no descenders on account that the capital letters have no descenders. Descenders just were not part of original Latin alphabet. Quite many fonts come with small caps and that should do the trick for you. That is if you can stand the fact that people think your screaming all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base-line shift on the specific letterforms to push letters above the baseline enough to eliminate them hanging below the baseline.

There are "calculator" style digital fonts that use distorted letters with reduced vertical resolution to fit the limited display space.